# C# WPF Window not Updating in foreach loop

Tags: c#, wpf, foreach, window

in my project I need to load "projects".
I am loading all this "projects" in a foreach loop.
In this foreach loop, I want to show a status window  with a progressbar, which gets updated everytime a new project got load.

My problem now is, that the status window with the progrssbar wont update.
It seems it is just "freezed" like all other windows in my project (I also let the programm printing what it is doing into a console).

Here is the Code:

```
        Status StatusWd = new Status();
        StatusWd.pb_Status.Maximum = animes.Length;
        StatusWd.SetStatusText("Animes in AnimeBibliothek laden...");
        StatusWd.Show();

        bool white = false;
        bool black = true;
        foreach (string anime in animes)
        {
            if (white)
            {
                //Not working..
                AB_Output.WriteLine(GetTime() + "Weißes User Control laden...");
                AddWhiteUcpToStk(anime);
                white = false;
                black = true;
            }                
            else if (black)
            {
                AB_Output.WriteLine(GetTime() + "Schwarzes User Control laden...(" + anime + ")");
                AddBlackUCPToStk(anime);
                //white = true;
                //black = false;
            }
            StatusWd.pb_Status.Value = Array.IndexOf(animes, anime);
        }
        StatusWd.Close();
```

It´s not just the progressbar which wont update. Also the labels in the window, which get updated when the value changes, wont change. I debuged it and the value from the progressbar changed and the label content changes...

Would be nice if you could explain me your solution.

LG Sinmson

Comment: The UI and your work runs on the same thread. You should write asynchronous loading methods for loading your projects. Without seeing the logic for reading your projects, I can't offer advice on making it asynchronous, but, you can use async, await and the TPL to implement it.

Answer (score 4):

Blocking the UI thread will do that....

**Any** time you are running a long operation, you need to make sure it is on some other thread, otherwise you will be seen as "non-responsive".

So, first thing is to move your loading onto another thread. `Thread`, `BackgroundWorker` and `Task` are all reasonable ways to do this. Then you need to marshal any UI changes *back* to the UI thread.

If you used `async` (and `Tasks`) then the framework does this for you. Similarly, if you use a proper MVVM pattern `PropertyChanged` events will automatically marshal onto the correct thread.

If you can't do it a "right" way, then marshal such changes yourself using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    //UI code ONLY
}), DispatcherPriority.Normal);
```

But do so only as a band-aid. Move to asynchronous or MVVM based code (or even better, both!)

Comment: Thanks, I´ll read something about the backgroundworker. Do you prefer to use the backgroundworker "all the time" or just when its about not freezing the gui?

Comment: @Sinmson Threading I make sure to do with long ops. That being said, you should *always* decouple your buisness logic (like this) from the UI, so it usually isn't an issue with proper design anyways. Do note that `BackgroundWorker` is a little dated. You may want to try `Task` first.